# Can't select dom element with jQuery from rendered template in Backbone.js in an Android app with Phonegap

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, backbone.js

I have the following template:

```
<div id="content">asdfsadfasfsaadsffas<br>
<a href="#list" data-role="button">Link button</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($("#content").html());
</script>
```

The logic of the application is working well and templates are getting correctly rendered, but the alert always shows `null` above for some reason. I haven't set the `el` property of the view, might that be a reason why this isn't working?

Also I've tried calling the function at the ready event, which lead to the same problem. However, the `onload` event seem to never be triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was effectively related to the `el` property in the `Backbone.View`.
A relevant article would be http://rockycode.com/blog/backbone-views-dynamic-dom/

I first tried setting the `el` property like so `el: $("#content")` that I picked up from a random article, but turns out the correct way was `el: "#content"`